# Android and Google-app-engine createuploadURL - how to pass additional parameters (i.e. email address)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, parameter-passing, image-uploading, blobstore

I'm able to use createuploadurl to successfully store a bitmap image.  My problem is that I want to pass in an email address parameter also to send the image to after.

Here is the code I tried to use:

```
//Code for uploading image within android

//Now upload the image
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
HttpParams postParams = new BasicHttpParams();
postParams.setParameter( "email", "someone@gmail.com" );
httppost.setParams(postParams);

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity( HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE );
byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
entity.addPart("imageField", new ByteArrayBody(ba, "myimage.jpg"));
httppost.setEntity(entity);

// Execute HTTP Post Request
response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

In the servlet code I then try to get the email param:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

//this comes up as null
if (req.getParameter("email") != null) {
    this.email = req.getParameter(email);
}

Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(req);
BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("imageField");
resp.setContentType("text/plain");

}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the "imageField" key in the android to the email address.

In the server side, get all the keys from the get upload methods.

```
Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(req);
 Iterator<String> iter = blobs.keySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String key = iter.next(); // your email
}
```